# Firebase Caching with AMP

Tags: firebase, browser-cache, amp-html, firebase-hosting

Firebase json configuration

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [{
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "/images/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)",
        "headers": [{
          "key": "Cache-Control",
          "value": "max-age=3600000"
        }]
      },
      {
        "source": "https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js",
        "headers": [{
          "key": "Cache-Control",
          "value": "max-age=3000000"
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried to use the cdn link straight from source but it did not work. Does anyone know how I can do the https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js

IMAGE of  Optimization for pagespeed insights i am trying to do

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do I'm 99.9% certain can't be done. AMP controls that file, therefore you can not set custom cache headers on it. Best to just ignore that issue in the Page Speed Insights test (all other page speed metric sites will hit on it to).

AMP requires the JS files to be served from their CDN so you can't pull it down to your server either to gain control of the cache headers.